# JS code added from codebehind doesn't run

Tags: c#, javascript

I wrote an application in ASP.Net I have a problem with centering a dynamically created popup. In the popup control I inserted the following code:

```
string script = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
script += "$(document).ready(setMargin();); ";
script += "function setMargin(){ ";
script += "var wid = $('MC_resultPopup_pnlResultPopup').width();";
script += "$('MC_resultPopup_pnlResultPopup').css('margin-left', wid/2 + 'px');}";
script += "</script>";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "SetAutoWidth", script);
```

But this code is not working. It does not even start. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the registerclientscriptblock method instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

I dont think the RegisterClientScriptInclude takes the script as parameter, only the url to the script.

Comment: I tried both but it didn't run. I might add that my control is on page wchich is a content of master page.

Comment: If you view the rendered html source in the browser, is the script rendered as well?

Answer (score 0):

The method your'e looking for is `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, not `RegisterClientScriptInclude`. As Tobias suggests, the latter is for referencing an external javascript file.